# How can I prevent CiviMail Bounce Processing from moving mail to "ignored" folder?

Tags: civimail

Since we have activated CiviMail Bounce Processing, our team members don't see regular incoming mail (which has nothing to do with CiviCRM) in the inbox of our main org account anymore.
The problem is that CiviCRM moves all email from the inbox to a subfolder CiviMail/ignored, thereby removing the mail from the inbox where our team usually would look.

Is there a way to prevent CiviCRM from moving "ignored" messages and just leave them in the inbox?
Or what is the intended workflow here? Do we have to set up a separate e-mail account that will just be used for sending out mass mailing from CiviCRM with a reply-to to our "normal" contact email?

Answer (score 2):

Bounce processing assumes that the account is dedicated to handling bounces.  You don't want to mix bounce handling with a mailbox used by users.

See all of the "CiviMail setup" chapter in the [System Administrator Guide](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/) and in particular:

- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#bounce-processing
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#verp-support
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#special-email-address-for-incoming-email
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/#adding-an-incoming-email-account-for-processing-bounces-andor-email-to-activities
- https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/civimail/inbound/#bounce-handling